# Heroku Error when pushing Ruby via Github

Tags: ruby, github, heroku

A friend of mine programmed me a website years ago. Unfortunately from one day to the next the website did not work anymore.

I do not have Ruby on my computer (I never had it before either).
I am currently trying to host the Website again on Heroku via Github (https://github.com/dtricc/zoquant) and I get the following error:

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDCqA.png)

**My Gemfile looks as follows:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.2.0'

gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.3'

gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'

gem 'puma', '~> 6.0.2'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'webpacker'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.6.1'
gem 'simple_form'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

---

**My Gemfile.lock looks as follows:**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.2)
      actionpack (= 5.2.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (7.0.3)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3)
      activejob (= 7.0.3)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3)
      activestorage (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
      net-imap (>= 0)
      net-pop (>= 0)
      net-smtp (>= 0)
    actiontext (7.0.3)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3)
      activestorage (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      globalid (>= 0.6.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionmailer (5.2.2)
      actionpack (= 5.2.2)
      actionview (= 5.2.2)
      activejob (= 5.2.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (7.0.3)
      actionview (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actionview (5.2.2)
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.2)
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
    activerecord (7.0.3)
      activemodel (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
    activestorage (7.0.3)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3)
      activejob (= 7.0.3)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (7.0.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.4.10.2)
      execjs
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bootsnap (1.4.1)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (11.0.0)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    crass (1.0.4)
    erubi (1.8.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.10.0)
    font-awesome-sass (5.6.1)
      sassc (>= 1.11)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.6.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.8.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.2)
      mimemagic (>= 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mimemagic (0.4.2)
      nokogiri (~> 1)
      rake (>= 0)
    mini_mime (1.0.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    msgpack (1.2.9)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    nio4r (2.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.10.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    pg (1.1.4)
    puma (3.12.0)
    rack (2.0.6)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (7.0.3)
      actioncable (= 7.0.3)
      actionmailbox (= 7.0.3)
      actionmailer (= 7.0.3)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3)
      actiontext (= 7.0.3)
      actionview (= 7.0.3)
      activejob (= 7.0.3)
      activemodel (= 7.0.3)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3)
      activestorage (= 7.0.3)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 7.0.3)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (5.2.2)
      actionpack (= 5.2.2)
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    sass (3.7.3)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sassc (2.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
      rake
    simple_form (4.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.9)
    turbolinks (5.2.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.20)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    webpacker (4.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby 
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  autoprefixer-rails
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  font-awesome-sass (~> 5.6.1)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (~> 5.2.2)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  simple_form
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webpacker

RUBY VERSION
   ruby (~> 3.2.0)
```

---

I would appreciate any help!

Best Lorenzo

I already changed the versions of some of the packages (I obtained the error that the packages are to old and not supported by Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into your [commit history in your GitHub account](https://github.com/dtricc/zoquant/compare/master..ef70d2c352ef843dc251e777b76428d3d9dfbca8), it feels like you tried to update the Ruby from 2.5.3 to 3.2.0 and the Ruby on Rails version from 5.2.2 to 7.0.3 in your project without doing any code changes.

Ruby 3.0 introduced some syntax changes. And upgrading two major versions of Ruby on Rails without having to change anything in the application, is usually not possible.

I advise reverting those changes and to restart the upgrade. But this time, only update in small incremental steps, following the suggestions from [the official Rails Guides about upgrading](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html).

Additionally, each Rails version supports or has preferred Ruby versions to run with. I suggest following the update path for Ruby and Ruby on Rails from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72422217/2483313).