# How should I upgrade an outdated ruby on rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a project that is currently running on rails 4~ and Ruby 2~, a lower version of it. I don't recall the exact iteration but it reached end of life about 8 years ago

For context, the original dev is gone. The project was developed directly in prod and there has never been a functional test environment. There is no merge history of any kind to reference, if that would even help.

I'm tasked with upgrading the project and fixing any bugs along the way. I bumped ruby up to 2.7~ and rails up to 5.2~, then all the gems until `bundle install` stopped giving errors.

That was a big milestone, but I've been struggling to get it running with `rails server`. I encountered a few issues that I corrected or commented out, now I'm stuck on an uninitialized method.

I tried all the known fixes and at this point, I'm thinking I need to try again with a different approach.

Different ideas that were floated have been:

- Remove all the code from the files and gradually reintroduce it.
- Remove entire modules and reintroduce them.
- Start asking online for advice.

I don't mind if the correct process is tedious, so long as it will be effective and I know it won't be entirely unproductive

I'm thinking that removing all non-essential components, just getting the landing page to work, would the best first step. But I have a limited knowledge of how RoR works and what is necessary for it to run at all.

Thanks everyone

What I tried:

- Upgrading all the gem files to versions that were compatible with a newer version of RoR.
- Addressing errors as they occurred to bypass or remove them entirely. Possibly creating more unexpected errors by removing pieces of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72421728/2483313

Answer (score 4):

There is no easy way to do this, but there is a way. The complexity of this *yak shaving* depends on the project itself, its dependencies, and other factors very hard to predict in advance. It could be easy, it could be near impossible, but it's likely just tedious and if approached systematically, will be something you can close out without ending up too frustrated.

Upgrading from Ruby 2 to the latest version, such as 3.2, won't be a huge deal. The biggest change in the 3.x series is how *kwargs* (keyword-arguments, or `**args`) are handled. You may want to upgrade your Ruby incrementally as I'm not sure Rails 4 works with Ruby 3.x.

As for Rails itself, there aren't too many breaking changes, but there are a lot of changes to how configuration is expressed. Remember you can always create a new project to compare how things *should* be configured in the current version of Rails using `rails new`, and this is something you'll want to reference when ensuring your various underpinnings like `application.rb` conform to the newer style.

Some of the biggest changes are in the [asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) which has changed multiple times in dramatic ways since version 4. Now you'll have options on how you want to configure it, so find an approach you're happy with and stick with that. Before it was just Sprockets.

Dependencies are the place where you'll have the most friction, often because you'll be using something that stopped being updated and has version pins that prevent Rails itself from being upgraded. You may need to swap out some of these for newer, supported versions. Hopefully this isn't too much of a hassle!

Comment: Ruby on Rails 6.1 was the first version of Rails supporting Ruby 3.0. Therefore, I suggest following [this path to update Ruby and Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72422217/2483313).

Comment: @spickermann Good job keeping that up to date. Great reference.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback. What you're describing is sort of what I've been figuring out, and it is reassuring to hear that the incremental upgrades are the most effective method. I'll apply your advice to my approach.

Comment: This project should really start with a code audit - which is going to be very hard if you don't know the language/framework. That will tell you if the existing code is even worth salvaging or if you would be better off with a fresh start with tests and decent coding practices.

Comment: @max Creating a new Rails project and transposing code bit by bit to it and testing as you go is also a method that works, though really it's more of a last resort as you do need to carefully reassemble everything in the new app.

Answer (score 1):

Systematically with careful testing and use of the upgrade guides.

1. Ensure you have good system tests and can rely on them.  Writing even some basic coverage now may save you time in manual testing through many iterations. Then look into what seem to be the "busy files" and consider adding any missing unit tests there.
2. Move to the **last version of rails 4**.  Test and fix everything you can.  Bump every gem you can while staying on rails 4 and keeping the system working.
3. Move to Rails 5.0 (not 5.2!).  Read the [Rails 4-5 upgrading guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) and check every thing suggested there.  Use your tests to ensure its all good at this point.  Upgrade the gems you can along the way.  Anytime you see a major version number change make sure you test the related functionality in your app and consult the gem's update docs.
4. Move to rails 5.1.  Run tests, update gems.  Consider reading [its upgrade guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/5_1_release_notes.html#upgrading-to-rails-5-1) if you hit issues.
5. Repeat step 4 for Rails 5.2.
6. Move to the last version of rails 5.2.
7. Repeat steps 3 - 6 for rails 6 & 7.  There are often upgrade blog posts detailing issues not covered by official guides.  They can often save you time.  You may also be able to jump from the X.0 -> X.2 series and skip a step.

###### Ruby version upgrades

The ruby version upgrades are somewhat less important (and less painful post 1.x).  I'd probably do those by jumping to the last version of 2.x first then wait till Rails 6.1 to bump to ruby 3.0.  You could probably jump to ruby 3.2 after everything else is done.

###### Un-maintained gems

You'll almost certainly run into gems that are no longer maintained.  In some cases you can find a replacement but it will often take a fair bit of effort to re-write those features to work with the new API.  Depending on your team it may be worth determining if a feature is no longer needed and could be dropped rather than investing in updating it.

###### Deploy along the way

Finally if this is an actively developed project, or even if its not it is probably worth deploying and running in production at major steps along the way.  Your merge will be insane if you try to do this all in one branch.