# Cannot do rails s because mime-types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mime-types

I am trying to run an application from another computer.
I'm on ruby ​​version 2.6.3 and rails version 5.0.7.2
It may be because of the mime types

But when I do `rails s` here is the error it gives me

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/deprecations.rb:3:in `require': /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/logger.rb:26: _1 is reserved for numbered parameter (SyntaxError)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/logger.rb:26: _2 is reserved for numbered parameter
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/logger.rb:26: _3 is reserved for numbered parameter
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/deprecations.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types.rb:3:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/columnar.rb:147:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/columnar.rb:147:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.3/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:6:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.3/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.3/lib/carrierwave.rb:95:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.3/lib/carrierwave.rb:95:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-video-06238933c2b9/lib/carrierwave/video.rb:2:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bundler/gems/carrierwave-video-06238933c2b9/lib/carrierwave/video.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:73:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:73:in `rescue in block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:196:in `require'
    from /home/null/Documents/labo/video-manipulator-master/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/null/Documents/labo/video-manipulator-master/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/null/Documents/labo/video-manipulator-master/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /home/null/Documents/labo/video-manipulator-master/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `require': cannot load such file -- carrierwave-video (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:196:in `require'
    from /home/null/Documents/labo/video-manipulator-master/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/null/Documents/labo/video-manipulator-master/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/null/Documents/labo/video-manipulator-master/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /home/null/Documents/labo/video-manipulator-master/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I tried to update mime-types but it didn't change anything.Do these two versions of rails and ruby ​​go together ?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run a Ruby on Rails 5.0 application with Ruby 3.0. That will certainly not work. Rails 5.0 only runs on Ruby < 2.5. When you plan to update your Ruby and Ruby on Rails versions, then I suggest [following these update steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72422217/2483313).

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously trying to run it with ruby 3 NOT ruby ​​version 2.6.3.

Install rvm :

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Then read and apply the end of the install log , regarding the "source some/path/on/your/machine"

Then run :

```
rvm install 2.6.3
```

then cd your project and :

```
bundle install
```

and relaunch your server.
it works fine on linuxes .